# Effect of order of task on variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

The experiment has the following setup,

People will go through a set of documents of different difficulty. The difficulty of these documents varies from on person to an other, and the documents are not always the same. At the end of the experiment, they will need to go through a post-task and from there we will measure a score of how well they did overall. The score kind of represents how familiar a participant is with the topic of the docs, and doesn't use the docs difficulty to caluclate.

```
                                               |     SCORE
USER1   5      3      3     ...        1       |       5
USER2   5      5      5     ...        3       |       2
USER3   3      4      5     ...        1       |       3
USER4   5      4      3     ...        2       |       6
USER5   5      1      3     ...        1       |       1
 ...
```

My question is how do you test whether the order in which participants go through the docs affects their score, and how to measure the effectiveness of the order towards the score?

Comment: Are you checking a small number of fixed orderings chosen a-priori, or are you sampling at random from the $10! = 3,628,800$ permutations?

Comment: The difficulty of the tasks are determined by the user (the user will assign a value of difficulty to the task), and there is a small fixed number of users.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Regarding the order the tasks are presented in, are you only using a small number of orderings chosen a-priori, or are you sampling at random from all possible permutations?

Comment: Neither.. I might have not explained the study well.. The tasks are different.. but I'm not interested in the tasks they go through, I'm interested in their difficulty how it affects their score.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your question is "how do you test **whether the order in which participants go through the docs** affects their score, and how to measure the effectiveness of the order towards the score?" What I'm trying to find out is what that order is. I recognize that the tasks are different, if they weren't, the question would be incoherent. Does every participant do the tasks in the order of task 1, task 2, task 3..., or do some do 1,2,3... & others ...,3,2,1, & others ...,2,...,3,...,1, etc? In other words, how did the participants end up with the orderings they had?

Comment: The participants actually choose the ordering they prefer. They'll be selecting 10 from a pool of docs, and then going through them in the order they specified, one by one. The difficulty of what they select differs, and the order of difficulty differs, and I'm trying to know if there's away to test if the order of difficulty of the docs they go through, one by one, affects their final score.

Comment: any ideas you can point me to?